# Creating component using Angular cli in VS 2017 Angular Template

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

I have installed below software in my System

- VS 2017- Version 15.3.3
- Node Version - 6.11.3
- Angular cli Version - 1.4.1

I want to create component using angular cli inside angular template in VS 2017

Below are the step I am doing but fail to achive the results

- Step 1) Create a Project with Angular Template in VS2017
- Step 2)Open Cmd - Create a dummy ng project for .angular-cli.json file outside the solution
- Step 3)Copy Pasting .angular-cli.json file to my solution under below folder structure 
  [M:\VS2017 Projects\Trail109\Trail109]
- Step 4)Changing from "root": "Src" to "root": "ClientApp"
- Step 5)then going inside the solution using cd command in cmd
- Step 6)and installing angular/cli for my solution using given command npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev
  [M:\VS2017 Projects\Trail109\Trail109>npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev]
- Step 7)after this going to components folders inside ClientApp using cd command in cmd
- Step 8)and using the given command ng g component myformname
  [M:\VS2017 Projects\Trail109\Trail109\ClientApp\app\components>ng g component myformname]
  but the above line gives me below given error

  Error: Path "ClientApp/" is invalid.
  Path "ClientApp/" is invalid.

Please help What is that I am missing....

Answer (score 2):

VS 2017 angular template has pre rendering enabled by default. If you haven't disabled that, please make sure after changing root to Client app

- Amend the .angular.cli : change as follows

  "root": "ClientApp",

  "outDir": "ClientApp/dist",
- Amend the ClientApp folder as follows

Rename app.module.client.ts to app.client.module.ts
Open app.client.module.ts: prepend the declaration with 3 dots “...” and wrap the declaration in brackets.

For example: [...sharedConfig.declarations, ]

Open boot-client.ts: update your import to use the new app.client.module reference.
For example: import { AppModule } from './app/app.client.module';

Comment: In my ClientApp\App Folder I only have app.module.browser.ts,app.module.server.ts,app.module.shared.ts and Under ClientApp Folder boot.browser.ts,boot.server.ts but as you mentioned I didn't find  app.module.client.ts,boot-client.ts

Comment: oh then the one app.module.browser.ts is your client one. make the same changes to that one

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project file in notepad.
2. find the tag name which stated with **SpaRoot**
3. And Replace your angular project folder name here.